# In angularjs, I have a filtered list of radio buttons and want to select the first?

Tags: angularjs, filter, radio-button, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a list of layers which I'm displaying:

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in layers | filter:isActive | orderBy:row.name">
    <td><input type="radio" id="{{ 'layerOption-' + row.key }}" name="layerOptions" ng-checked="row.checked" /></td>
    <td>{{ row.name }}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

I get the list via:

```
$scope.isActive = function(layer) { return layer.zoned === $scope.showZonedLayers; };

$scope.layers = values.layers.map(function(item, key) { return { 
    key: key, 
    name: item, 
    checked: key === 0 ? true : false, 
    zoned: item.indexOf("Zones") > 0
} });
```

This will set the first element in the list set, but this can be filtered out by the filter. How do I set the first unfiltered/visible radio box to checked?

Can this be done via a filter? If not, what's the equivalent in angular to jquery grep?

Answer (score 1):

Wow, I love angular. Found a very easy solution:

```
ng-checked="{{$first}}"
```

will take care of it. And I can get rid of the checked property on the array.

UPDATE:

Setting ng-checked=$first doesn't update the bound value, so it's a bit useless as you can't query the selected value back. I rewrote my code to dump the filter and do it in code instead:

```
$scope.layers = values.layers.map(function(item, key) { return { 
    key: key, 
    name: item, 
    zoned: item.indexOf("Zones") > 0
} }).filter(function(item) { return item.zoned === $scope.showZonedLayers; });
```

But that means I have to have a ng-change callback on the checkbox that binds to `$scope.showZonedLayers`. Just wondering if there is a more elegant way?

Comment: Actually, that doesn't quite do what I want to. While it ticks the first item, it doesn't set the value.

Comment: you dont need to interpolate `{{$first}}`, you can just simply put `ng-checked="$first"`.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to simply use:

```
ng-checked="$first"
```